# Why downvote , what is wrong in the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Create DML(insert script) using JSON representation of table data in java for Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513839/create-dmlinsert-script-using-json-representation-of-table-data-in-java-for-or)

Comment: What about the comments on the question was inadequate feedback for you to notice the problems with your question?  Did you read through the help center articles on how to ask an appropriate question?  Which of the aspects of a good question do you feel that question does and does not meet?

Comment: Library recommendation questions are never appreciated and off topic for the site.

Comment: I have modified the question, now it should appear in post..

Answer (score 12):

According to [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Unfortunately that's precisely what your question asks for...

> Is there any library which does already

You also say

> I want to achieve the output with less lines of code.

Less lines than what? Where is this code that you're asking us to optimise?

Finally you've been asked for clarification in comments to which you have not responded i.e.

> Can you please add the sample JSON and schema description

I see json but no schema. If your question does not contain enough information to answer it then it often gets downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

In your question you ask for a library recommendation. Such questions are off-topic, as per [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Your question should have been closed because of this, but [it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55513839/timeline#review_22659102) it slipped through the net.